# Making an HTTP request within the same Docker network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a few services running in different docker containers, as per my docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  rest:
    build:
      context: './service/'
    image: persian_rest:latest
    container_name: persian_rest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - persian_net
    volumes:
      - persian_volume:/data
  scheduler:
    build:
      context: './scheduler/'
    image: persian_scheduler:latest
    container_name: persian_scheduler
    networks:
      - persian_net
  ui:
    build:
      context: './ui/'
    image: persian_ui:latest
    container_name: persian_ui
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - persian_net
  database:
    image: 'mongo:latest'
    container_name: 'persian_database'
    networks:
      - persian_net
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=persian_admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - persian_volume:/data
volumes:
  persian_volume:
networks:
  persian_net:
    driver: bridge
```

I have my UI *persian_ui* service making HTTP request to the REST service *persian_rest*. I thought that since they were in the same network, I would just make a request to http://persian_rest:8080/api

However, when I do make that request, it fails to find that resource:
[image]

Does anyone know why my containers joined by the same network are not able to perform requests?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would expect to use persian_net:8080

Comment: @SydneyY that's what I am using

Comment: Your question says you're using persian_rest, not persian_net, are you sure? Also, that error looks like a chrome error. What do you type in the URL bar to see your UI?

Comment: @SydneyY so it wouldn't be persian_rest? I access the UI through localhost:5000. Also, accesing it using persian_net doesn't work either GET http://persian_net:8080/api/personal-website/website net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are looking at a webpage at localhost:5000. You requested the webpage from the server localhost:5000 and it complied and sent you a webpage which is now sitting on your computer.

If you now want to access an API on the same server as the webpage, you can make another request to localhost but this time port 8080. localhost:8080/api.

The webpage in the browser is on the client-side, and the names you've given your containers are for reference inside the server. From outside the server, currently the reference is localhost.

Comment: if I use localhost, I am not going through persian_net. I would be making the request to my machine, which would then get mapped to the docker container right? Any way I can just have it map to the docker container directly?

Comment: No, you can't. You are outside the machine, so you have to make the request to the machine. I know it can seem like localhost:5000 means you are in the machine, but it was simply a one-off request to the machine.

Comment: Actually, you could make a request to localhost:5000 if localhost:5000 is a web server capable of making it's own http requests. So now you request localhost:5000/index.html and it sends the HTML. You send localhost:5000/api, the docker ui makes a http request internally, and sends the result back to the browser. But it depends on what you're actually running in your container.

Comment: I understand. What if I was accessing the database from persian_rest service. Would I also use mongodb://localhost... or mongodb://persian_database...?

Comment: I'm not sure, actually. It would either be localhost or persian_net. localhost because this time they're operating on the same machine, or persian_net because Docker named the network persian_net.